# Using Grid to layer items over each other

Tags: css

I am using absolute positioning to layer `div` `one`, `two`, `three` (and cover `main`). Would it be possible to achieve the same with CSS grid?

- `div.main` is always displayed
- `div` `one`, `two`, `three` will be shown when needed

**Update:** Toggle button added for better visualisation

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div.content');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const on = document.querySelector('.on');
  on?.classList.remove('on');
  (on?.nextElementSibling || div.firstElementChild).classList.add('on');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
 }
 
.content {
  width: 15em;
  height: 8em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.one.on,
.two.on,
.three.on {
  display: block;
}


.one {
  background: #fef8;
}

.two {
  background: #fec8;
}

.three {
  background: #cdc8;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main on">This is main</div>
  <div class="one">This is one</div>
  <div class="two">This is two</div>
  <div class="three">This is three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `div` just need to stack on each other, perhaps a simple implement would be setting `content` a grid of a single cell, and have all the `div` placed in `grid-area: 1/1/1/1`.

Example: (with a simple display toggle)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div > div");

let i = 1;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (i === 4) {
    divs.forEach((div) => div.classList.remove("on"));
    i = 1;
    return;
  }
  divs[i - 1].classList.toggle("on");
  divs[i].classList.toggle("on");
  i++;
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 15em;
  height: 20em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: 1/1/1/1;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-area: 1/1/1/1;
}

.one.on,
.two.on,
.three.on {
  display: block;
}

button {
 padding: 6px;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.one {
 background-color: rgba(100, 149, 237, 0.25);
}

.two {
background-color: rgba(34, 139, 34, 0.25);
}

.three {
background-color: rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">This is main</div>
  <div class="one">This is one</div>
  <div class="two">This is two.</div>
  <div class="three">This is three.</div>
</div>
```